# how to turn one set with 5 elements into 5 sets each with one element in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Lets say I have 2 sets of lists.

```
set1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
set2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

From here I've tried to subtract set1 from set2 in order to get `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`, and I've done so by saying print `[x for x in set2 if x not in set1]` The output is just `set2`, because there is only one element in set 2, and that is the list of all natural numbers up to and including 10.

So my question is how do I turn `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` into `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]]`?

I know this is a basic question, but I'm new and I couldn't find any other questions like this. Please answer with answers that help in general and not only in this situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a set, that's a list...

Comment: `[[x] for x in data]`.

Comment: Why do you say that there is only one element in `set2`? You defined `set2` with `set2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

Comment: Your story does not make much sense: there are 10 elements in `set2`.

Comment: It's not at all clear why you think getting a list of lists will help you resolve your larger issue. If your original lists are as you show in the first code block, the list comprehension you show in the next paragraph should work just fine. Getting a list of lists will not help, in fact it would make what you actually want harder to achieve. Is your `set2` really `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sets to solve the stated problem

```
set1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
set2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

set(set2) - set(set1)

Out[18]: {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}
```

the list comprehension works too, did you have a different result?

```
[e for e in set2 if e not in set1]

Out[17]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
new_s = [[i] for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
```